# How to get kitten used to wet food (transition from BARF)?

Tags: cats, diet, can-food, digestion, cat-food

TL;DR at bottom.

I've been posting a lot lately, as I've gotten a new kitten.
I'm told by the previous owner, that she is used to dry food and BARF, apparently.

A week or so after bringing her home, I started with a small quantity of wet food. Sadly, she went and ate quite a lot from my other kitten's bowl (I should have been more careful).

Sure enough, the next day she had diarrhea. I've been doing some reading on the subject, and I've started mixing a small quantity of wet food with some carrot soup (see [Moro Soup for pets](https://www.aniforte.co.uk/blogs/news/dogs-diarrhea-how-morosoup-can-help-your-dogs-intestinal-issues)). As this recipe was invented by a German (originally to save kids with diarrhea from dying), there are many more resources in German of people and vets recommending it for both, cats and dogs.

I've started doing this 3 days ago. Now, while her stool got slightly better, it's still soft. I feel like the small improvement is from her eating less wet food, and not really from the carrot soup (but I'm not sure, who knows). She also doesn't seem to like the carrot taste much, so she eats way less than usually (and compensates with dry food).

I'm thinking of not giving her wet food for a week or two, until she has normal stool again, and then start over with wet food. Is that a good idea? Also, what's the best way to get a kitten used to wet food (or transition from BARF to wet food).

**TL;DR:**

Kitten used to BARF has diarrhea with canned wet food. I plan on reseting her stomach by only feeding dry food for a week or two, and then start with wet food again. What's the best way to transition her from BARF to wet food, without the risk of her having soft stool/diarrhea?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is BARF?